# Is day of the month a cyclic or a seasonal effect?

Tags: time-series, seasonality

Let's say we are performing an analysis on daily time series data that exhibit a sales pattern w.r.t day of the month. Let's say people get their salary on 14th and we can see an strong effect on sales the upcoming days after 14th. Is this effect considered a cyclic or a seasonal?

As I see it this effect does not have an exact period within each cycle, thus it is a cyclic effect since every month does not have the same amount of days. If every month had the same amount of days this would be considered seasonal.

Answer (score 0):

In the ESS guidelines on seasonal adjustment (p. 6), the definition of seasonality states that

> Usual seasonal fluctuations mean those movements which recur with similar intensity in the same season each year and which, on the basis of the past movements of the time series in question and under normal circumstances, can be expected to recur.

So from this definition infra-annual periodic are not considered seasonal. Yet, in experimentally adjusted daily time series, weekly and monthly recurring effects are adjusted for (e.g. [German truck toll data](https://www.destatis.de/EN/Service/EXDAT/Datensaetze/truck-toll-mileage.html)). This shows that the distinction between seasonal and infra-annual cyclical effects are often not done in practice. That length of the month varies is taken care of in many applications (e.g. [Ollech, 2022](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/jtse-2020-0028/html)). The same is true for the length of the years of course, as we sometimes have 366 instead of 365 days.